# Can you use an iframe to display streaming webrtc video?

Tags: iframe, webrtc

I have a site that uses a mesh network and webrtc to stream video? https://ironkata.herokuapp.com/

In order to reduce bandwidth I thought that maybe I could use an iframe instead of individually broadcasting all the streams.  When I place the link above in an iframe it showed blank.

`<iframe src="https://ironkata.herokuapp.com/"/>`

https://codepen.io/niko8888/pen/LYEbeBp

Is this feasible?  How do I make the iframe work if so?

Comment: How would that reduce bandwidth? I don't understand.

Comment: Add `allow="camera 'src';microphone 'src'"` to the iframe.

Comment: @jib Not sure if bandwidth is the correct term here but on this mesh network I can only handle about 5 video connections before it becomes very slow.  That shows up as 25 streams in the web rtc internals.  I tried adding what u suggested above to the iframe but i still dont see the vide.  https://codepen.io/niko8888/pen/LYEbeBp

Comment: Oh wait it works!!!!

Comment: But now it's capturing the media source from my iframe.  The idea is that it got the video from another tab, and only displayed through the iframe.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but iframes don't give you more resources from what I know. MediaStreamTrack objects can't cross document boundaries.